# How to open ports?

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I recently installed a firewall called "firewall-applet" and now I can't share my internet through ethernet cord   I tried all of these  with no success

```
sudo apt-get --purge  remove firewall-applet
sudo iptables -F
sudo ufw disable
```

next I did nmap localhost

Not shown: 996 closed ports

PORT    STATE SERVICE

23/tcp  open  telnet

25/tcp  open  smtp

139/tcp open  netbios-ssn

445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

I tried reinstalling the program there's no way to disable the firewall

please help ;(

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall-applet is a tray applet for `firewalld`.  Check to see if `firewalld` is running on your host.  Firewall-applet and `firewalld` are both installed separately, so there is a good chance when you remove firewall-applet, `firewalld` is still installed and running.

```
ps -ef | grep firewalld
```

if it is running, you can remove it by typing in:

```
sudo apt-get remove firewalld
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: that does not really open a port nor configure sharing a network connection nor configure NAT. Why are we removing something rather then understanding what the OP wants and advising configuration.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen because he set up a firewall and wants to remove them.  I was only trying to help remove what was the back for the firewall-applet, that is all.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen they are two different applications.  Firewalld is installed separately then firewall-applet.  The manpage shows it as a tray applet for firewalld.  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/firewall-applet.1.html

Comment: I am familiar with such things. IMO you should be explaining how to configure firewalld, either with the applet or any way you wish.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen He asked to remove the firewall, that is what he asked.  I gave an answer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen why can't you let the person asking the question decide if it is going to work for them or not?

Comment: I do not see a request to remove firewalld. At this point it is not clear what the cause of the problem may be and it is almost certainly the need to configure networking, although I am not sure if it a routing / port forwarding / NAT problem or a problem of configuring the local firewall or perhaps even the local services.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ***I tried reinstalling the program there's no way to disable the firewall*** is in his question.  He never mentioned removing firewalld, as he only mentioned firewall-applet.  There is a chance he missed uninstalling that.

Comment: Thank you it worked great I uninstalled firewalld rebooted and reset the connections and it worked :) I would vote the answer up, but i don't have enough reputation I marked it as answer though. Thanks you helped me a lot.

Comment: @thebluesquirel you're very welcome!

Comment: @thebluesquirel +1 for you to help you on your way in reputation.  :)

Comment: @thebluesquirel Thank you very much!  Glad I could be of assistance to you!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

firewalld can be controlled through the firewall-cmd tool.  To open port 22 temporarily use:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=22/tcp
```

To add it permanently (so it remains open when you reboot), you will also need to use:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=22/tcp
```